# Error data.table/tibble inside myfunc has grouping setp and myfunc is used on a grouped master DT[, myfunc(v1,v2), mygruop]

Tags: r, function, group-by, data.table, grouping

Really puzezling case: I wrote a function that combines two same length vectors (v1,v2) into a single strings by eliminating repetitions in v1 and preserving all values of v2 associated with each unique value of v1. This function works fine in the test examples. However it breaks when it is applied by groups of a master data.table.

```
reducemix_q_text <- function(charvar,reducevar){
  d <- data.table(charvar,reducevar)
  t <- substitute(reducevar)
  d2 <- d[,.(gs=paste0(reducevar,collapse=',')),charvar]
  d2[,out:= paste0(t,'(',gs,'): ',charvar)]
  d2$out %>% paste0(collapse ='; ') %>% return
}

#reprex tests: OK
t2 <- c('a','a','b')
q2 <- 0:2
reducemix_q_text(t2,q2)
[1] "q2(0,1): a; q2(2): b"

dt <- data.table(t=c(t2,t2), mygroup=c('w','w','s','s'))
dt[,.(tex=reducemix_q_text(t2,q2)) , by=mygroup]
   mygroup                  tex
1:       w q2(0,1): a; q2(2): b
2:       s q2(0,1): a; q2(2): b
```

the function works even when used grouped by, as per the last line. However when I try to use the exact same syintax on my actual data I get the error:

```
dics[,.(tex=reducemix_q_text(desc,q)) , by=.(a,b,tab,varname,type)]
 Error in `[.data.table`(d, , .(gs = paste0(reducevar, collapse = ",")),  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type closure. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

Any idea about why is this breaking?

I also reimplemented the function with dplyr only functions but get another error when applying by groups in my own master data.table. Again, it passes the tests, but fails on the actual data:

```
reducemix_q_text2 <- function(charvar,reducevar){
  d <- tibble(charvar,reducevar)
  t <- substitute(reducevar)
  d2 <- d %>% group_by(charvar) %>% mutate(gs=paste0(reducevar,collapse=','))
  d2 %>% 
    mutate(out=paste0(t,'(',gs,'): ',charvar)) %>% .$out %>% paste0(collapse ='; ') %>% return
}
reducemix_q_text2(t2,q2)
dt[,.(tex=reducemix_q_text(t2,q2)) , by=mygroup]
dics[,.(tex=reducemix_q_text2(desc,q)) , by=.(a,b,tab,varname,type)]
 Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `charvar` is a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: `desc()` is a [tag:dplyr] function.  I tested it with a column named `desc` within the `dt` and could not reproduce your error. In other words, your variable is a function - if you think that one of your column names is `desc`, you should double check your names first.

Comment: @Cole, you nailed it. Thank you so much. I was not aware of `dplyr::desc` and was wondering why the debugger kept making my internal variables into functions... Could you provide this as an answer. This may be useful for others in the future, but I could also delete the question if not appropriate.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I would lean towards deleting as it's kind of typo adjacent.